# Add last edited date to WordPress comments

Tags: wordpress, comments, last-modified

Does anyone know a way to display the timestamp for when a WordPress comment was last edited? (For example, see comments on the Moz blog.) I've searched the Codex and Google, and can't seem to find anything... It doesn't appear to be available in the list on this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, there are no built-in way to output the date of edit, because wordpress don't store this info in database.

You have to use some plugin, that will store edit-time in commentmeta (or some another place) and then you will be able to output it.